# Inflating view taking too much time in onCreateView in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, include

I've using the `Fragment` inside the `Navigation Drawer`.
In Drawer there are 7 more option menus are presents and all other working fine.
Only this fragment tasking 3sec time to show the views.

I've find using debug mode, below this only line taking that much time to execute.

```
final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vehicle_inspection,container,false);
```

Moreover I've using 4 include layout in XML part.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lat_inspection_vendor_name_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_05dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_inspection_vendor_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/margin_15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_inspection_function_layout"
        layout="@layout/fragment_inspection_function_layout_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lat_inspection_vendor_name_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_05dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_inspection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include_inspection_function_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/fragment_inspection_vendor_details_card" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lat_inspection_form"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <include layout="@layout/fragment_inspection_vehicle_form_row_card" />

                <include layout="@layout/fragment_inspection_vehicle_features_row_card" />

                <include layout="@layout/fragment_inspection_vehicle_form_penalty_row_card" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope include part is not affect inflate view.

I've using 26- EditText, 26-checkbox and 30-TextViews inside the include layout.
My concern is Inflating too much number of views only taking time.

Please assist me to encounter this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a Recyclerview instead of ScrollView?

Comment: There are some conflict validation is there so that I've using ScrollView. Is this the  case for this problem?.

Comment: Dynamic view inflating is slow and it freezes the main thread if the number of views is more.

Comment: Yes, You are right more number of view only affecting the execution. can you give me the solution to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because too much view's in your layout file and yes include part affect your inflation process. Try to reduce number of view.
Share you layout design image so i can give you a suggestion.

Comment: You are right, There is no option to reduce number of view. All views are important. can you give me any other solution.

Comment: Share you layout design image so i can give you a suggestion.

Comment: Dear @Suraj unable to share image. But now I've catch the issue. Inflating too much views only taking time.There are I've using 26- EditText, 26-checkbox and 30-TextViews.

Comment: Not yet. I just found the reason, need a solution

Comment: You need to use recycler view in that case

Comment: Okay I'll try and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are showing some high resolution image or any other background resource so it may happen to take some time to draw view in your fragment

Comment: Yes I'm aware this point, But  I didn't show any image inside layout.